# How can I link with libquadmath?

Tags: gcc, linker, fortran

When I try to build my application by gfortran 4.6 I get the following error:

`profcn103.for:(.text+0x7e76b): undefined reference to log10q_`

I tried to specify `-lquadmath` option it didn't help.

When I look at library by `nm` I get the following:

`log10q.o: 00000000 T log10q`

I use Ubuntu 10.10 (i686). I tried manually compiled gcc-4.6.2 and gcc-4.6 from ppa repository.

It looks like a problem with mangling of names. What can I do with it?

Answer (score 0):

What platform, and where did you get your copy of gfortran? In case you use windows, the equation.com builds are known to be broken wrt quadmath. Otherwise, it should work.

And no, you don't need to explicitly add -lquadmath; the gfortran driver does it  automatically.

Answer (score 0):

It's my fault. I had to use usual `log10` and not `log10q` because gfortran automatically invoke needed functions.